# C# - How to add an Excel Worksheet programmatically - Office XP / 2003

Tags: c#, excel, com, office-interop, worksheet

I am just starting to fiddle with Excel via C# to be able to automate the creation, and addition to an Excel file.

I can open the file and update its data and move through the existing worksheets. My problem is how can I add new sheets?

I tried:

```
Excel.Worksheet newWorksheet;
newWorksheet = (Excel.Worksheet)excelApp.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(
                Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

But I get below *COM Exception* and my googling has not given me any answer.

> Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Source is: "Interop.Excel"

I am hoping someone maybe able to put me out of my misery.

Comment: The exception is: Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC   
Source is: "Interop.Excel"

Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 44, accepted):

You need to add a COM reference in your project to the **"`Microsoft Excel 11.0 Object Library`"** - or whatever version is appropriate.

This code works for me:

```
private void AddWorksheetToExcelWorkbook(string fullFilename,string worksheetName)
{
    Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
    Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
    Sheets xlSheets = null;
    Worksheet xlNewSheet = null;

    try {
        xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

        if (xlApp == null)
            return;

        // Uncomment the line below if you want to see what's happening in Excel
        // xlApp.Visible = true;

        xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(fullFilename, 0, false, 5, "", "",
                false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                true, false, 0, true, false, false);

        xlSheets = xlWorkbook.Sheets as Sheets;

        // The first argument below inserts the new worksheet as the first one
        xlNewSheet = (Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
        xlNewSheet.Name = worksheetName;

        xlWorkbook.Save();
        xlWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing,Type.Missing,Type.Missing);
        xlApp.Quit();
    }
    finally {
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlNewSheet);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheets);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
        xlApp = null;
    }
}
```

> Note that you want to be very careful about [properly cleaning up and releasing your COM object references](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/158706/how-to-properly-clean-up-excel-interop-objects-in-c). Included in that StackOverflow question is a useful rule of thumb: *"Never use 2 dots with COM objects"*. In your code; you're going to have real trouble with that. *My demo code above does NOT properly clean up the Excel app, but it's a start!*

Some other links that I found useful when looking into this question:

- [Opening and Navigating Excel with C#](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/office/csharp_excel.aspx)
- [How to: Use COM Interop to Create an Excel Spreadsheet (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173186(VS.80).aspx)
- [How to: Add New Worksheets to Workbooks](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6fczc37s(VS.80).aspx)

According to MSDN

> To use COM interop, you must have
>   administrator or Power User security
>   permissions.

Hope that helps.

Comment: I got a COMException on this on the Add() call if it is a XLSM file.

Answer (score 5):

Would like to thank you for some excellent replies. @AR., your a star and it works perfectly. I had noticed last night that the `Excel.exe` was not closing; so I did some research and found out about how to release the COM objects. Here is my final code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;
using System.Reflection;
using System.IO;
using Excel;

namespace testExcelconsoleApp
{
    class Program
    {
        private String fileLoc = @"C:\temp\test.xls";

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Program p = new Program();
            p.createExcel();
        }

        private void createExcel()
        {
            Excel.Application excelApp = null;
            Excel.Workbook workbook = null;
            Excel.Sheets sheets = null;
            Excel.Worksheet newSheet = null;

            try
            {
                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(fileLoc);
                if (file.Exists)
                {
                    excelApp = new Excel.Application();
                    workbook = excelApp.Workbooks.Open(fileLoc, 0, false, 5, "", "",
                                                        false, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
                                                        true, false, 0, true, false, false);

                    sheets = workbook.Sheets;

                    //check columns exist
                    foreach (Excel.Worksheet sheet in sheets)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(sheet.Name);
                        sheet.Select(Type.Missing);

                        System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheet);
                    }

                    newSheet = (Worksheet)sheets.Add(sheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
                    newSheet.Name = "My New Sheet";
                    newSheet.Cells[1, 1] = "BOO!";

                    workbook.Save();
                    workbook.Close(null, null, null);
                    excelApp.Quit();
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(newSheet);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(sheets);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(workbook);
                System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(excelApp);

                newSheet = null;
                sheets = null;
                workbook = null;
                excelApp = null;

                GC.Collect();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for all your help.

Answer (score 2):

Another "Up Tick" for AR..., but if you don't have to use interop I would avoid it altogether.  This product is actually quite interesting:
http://www.clearoffice.com/ and it provides a very intuitive, fully managed, api for manipulation excel files and seems to be free. (at least for the time being)  [SpreadSheetGear](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) is also excellent but pricey.

my two cents.

Answer (score 1):

> Do not forget to include *Reference* to **`Microsoft Excel 12.0/11.0 object Library`**

```
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;
// Include this Namespace
```

```
Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application xlApp = null;
Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = null;
Excel.Sheets xlSheets = null;
Excel.Worksheet xlNewSheet = null;
string worksheetName ="Sheet_Name";
object readOnly1 = false;

object isVisible = true;

object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

try
{
    xlApp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();

    if (xlApp == null)
        return;

    // Uncomment the line below if you want to see what's happening in Excel
    // xlApp.Visible = true;

    xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"C:\Book1.xls", missing, readOnly1, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, missing, isVisible, missing, missing, missing);

    xlSheets = (Excel.Sheets)xlWorkbook.Sheets;

    // The first argument below inserts the new worksheet as the first one
    xlNewSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    xlNewSheet.Name = worksheetName;

    xlWorkbook.Save();
    xlWorkbook.Close(Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
    xlApp.Quit();
}
finally
{
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlNewSheet);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlSheets);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);
    System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    //xlApp = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use OLEDB to create and manipulate Excel files. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/151005/create-excel-xls-and-xlsx-file-from-c#151048) for links and samples.

Answer (score 0):

Here are a couple things I figured  out:

1. You can't open more than one instance of the same object at the same time. For Example if you instanciate a new excel sheet object called `xlsheet1` you have to release it before creating another excel sheet object ex `xlsheet2`. It seem as COM looses track of the object and leaves a zombie process on the server.
2. Using the open method associated with `excel.workbooks` also becomes difficult to close if you have multiple users accessing the same file. Use the Add method instead, it works just as good without locking the file. eg. `xlBook = xlBooks.Add("C:\location\XlTemplate.xls")`
3. Place your garbage collection in a separate block or method after releasing the COM objects.

Answer (score 0):

**COM** is definitely not a good way to go. More specifically, it's a no go if you're dealing with web environment...

I've used with success the following open source projects:

- ExcelPackage for OOXML formats (Office 2007)
- NPOI for .XLS format (Office 2003)

Take a look at these blog posts:

[Creating Excel spreadsheets .XLS and .XLSX in C#](http://www.leniel.net/2009/07/creating-excel-spreadsheets-xls-xlsx-c.html)

[NPOI with Excel Table and dynamic Chart](http://www.leniel.net/2009/10/npoi-with-excel-table-and-dynamic-chart.html)

Answer (score 0):

This is what i used to add addtional worksheet

```
Workbook workbook = null;
Worksheet worksheet = null;

workbook = app.Workbooks.Add(1);
workbook.Sheets.Add();

Worksheet additionalWorksheet = workbook.ActiveSheet;
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem application-level add-in in VSTO, the exception HRESULT: 0x800A03EC when adding new sheet.

> The error code 0x800A03EC (or -2146827284) means NAME_NOT_FOUND; in
>   other words, you've asked for something, and Excel can't find it.

Dominic Zukiewicz @ [Excel error HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while trying to get range with cell's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891394/excel-error-hresult-0x800a03ec-while-trying-to-get-range-with-cells-name)

Then I finally realized **ThisWorkbook** triggered the exception. **ActiveWorkbook** went OK.

```
Excel.Worksheet newSheetException = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, sheet, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
Excel.Worksheet newSheetNoException = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets.Add(Type.Missing, sheet, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```