# Adding formula to cell Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC

Tags: c#, excel, vsto

I'm trying to add a formula to cell but i got the error
**Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC** 
There are lots of posts with similar issues however none could help me plus i'm not doing any fancy formula's what i'm doing wrong?

```
 Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture =
 new System.Globalization.CultureInfo("en-US");
 workbook = application.Workbooks.Open(Helper.GetLocalInstalationFolder() +
             @"\IMC.xltx", 0, false, 5, "", "", true, XlPlatform.xlWindows, "\t", false,
                                                       false, 0, true, 1, 0);
 worksheet = workbook.Worksheets["Report"];
 var rowValue = 0;
 for (int i = 2; i <= LastRow; i++)
 {
     rowValue = i - 1;
     for (int j = 1; j <= 37; j++)
     {
          worksheet.Cells[i, j] = MyArray[rowValue, j];

     }
     // I tried all the following all give the same exception:
     worksheet.Range[i, 38].Formula = "=3+4"; 
     worksheet.get_Range("R" + i + "C38").FormulaR1C1 = "=3+4";
     worksheet.Range[i, 38].FormulaR1C1 = "=3+4";
     worksheet.get_Range("R" + i + "C38").Formula = "=3+4";
   }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a crappy exception and doesn't mean anything more than you slamming Excel with processing requests at a rate that it cannot keep up with.  Your program essentially looks like a hyper-active user that's entering formulas at a rate of one per microsecond.

The workaround is to go slower by intentionally sleeping or to force Excel to do less work.  You will very probably fix it in this case by assigning the [Application.Calculation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff821260.aspx) property.  Set it to manual before you start putting formulas into cells.  And back to auto after you're done.

More good advice in [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/cristib/archive/2012/04/27/vsto-amp-vba-how-to-troubleshoot-excel-memory-and-performance-problems-caused-by-inefficient-code-loops.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this brings you into the right direction->

[a link] (http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/470089/Exception-from-HRESULT-0x800A03EC-Error)

Comment: Avoid link only answers. Good link though.

Answer (score 0):

in my case I was missing double-quotes in the HYPERLINK formula arguments, i.e. the formula itself was wrong. i tried a valid formula, like ..Cell(x,y).Formula = "=MIN(2)" and it worked, therefore that was the case..

Answer (score 0):

[Hans Passant](https://stackoverflow.com/users/17034/hans-passant) is correct, but there may be additional settings needed to enable Excel's ability to handle the cadence of your code operations.

Here's a good set of options to make Excel capable of processing requests faster:  [Turn Automatic Calculations Off/On](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/on-off-calculations/)

A summary of what worked for me:

```
    using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;

    public class ExcelAppWrapper : IDisposable
    {
        private Excel.Application _application;

        public ExcelAppWrapper()
        {
            _application = new Excel.Application { Visible = true };
            _application.Workbooks.Add(Missing.Value);
            //there must be a workbook before setting Application.Calculation
            ConfigureApplication(false);
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            ConfigureApplication(true);
        }

        private void ConfigureApplication(bool enable)
        {
            _application.Calculation = enable ? XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic : XlCalculation.xlCalculationManual;
            _application.EnableEvents = enable;
            _application.ScreenUpdating = enable;
            _application.DisplayStatusBar = enable;
        }
    }
```