# C# Excel interop merge not working

Tags: c#, excel, merge, excel-interop

I have defined a range with:

```
Range range =  ws.Range[ws.Cells[7, 1], ws.Cells[7, 4]];
```

and checked with

```
range.Interior.Color = rgbBlueViolet;
```

So the range is correct since I see it coloured.

But when I do

```
range.Merge(true);
```

I get the following exception:

> {System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException (0x800A03EC): Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC
>      at System.RuntimeType.ForwardCallToInvokeMember(String memberName, BindingFlags flags, Object target, Int32[] aWrapperTypes, MessageData& msgData)
>      at Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range.Merge(Object Across)

which I can't understand.

My goal is to merge the first 4 columns toghether which to me seems legit.

Thank you for any help
Patrick

Comment: You can try merging the range manually from Excel to see what the error is or maybe `range.Merge(false);`. There are few cases in which merge is not allowed.

Comment: Alas no. Manually it works perfectly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok the problem was that a range to be merged has to be selected first. And to do that the worksheet can't be minimized. Thus the code is:

```
Application app = new Application();
app.Visible = false;
app.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlNormal; <---not minimized   
...
Range r = ws.Range[ws.Cells[row + 7, 1], ws.Cells[row + 7, 5]];
r.Select(); <-----necessary
r.Merge(false);
```

Comment: A thousand thanks!!! This was happening to me on Windows 10, Excel 2016 and this fixed it. The odd thing is that it worked fine having window minimized on some computers but not others. Windows is getting too fast/smart for it's own britches.

Comment: More about "crappy exception" from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC http://stackoverflow.com/a/20424879/2559297

Comment: Also I didn't need to Select; just set app.WindowState = XlWindowState.xlNormal