# Calculate specific Date in powershell

Tags: excel, powershell

I'm a beginner in powershell

```
$test = ("=7*" + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,9).Text + "+DATE(" + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8).Text + ";1;3)-WEEKDAY(DATE(" + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8).Text + ";1;3))-2")
$newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1) = $test
```

Result to an incomprehensive error : Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC

this is what I want to put in my cell :

```
echo $test
=7*40+DATE(2014;1;3)-WEEKDAY(DATE(2014;1;3))-2
```

How can i resolve it ? Thx ! and sorry for my poor english :'(

**Edit**

I did :

```
$test = '=7*' + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,9).Text + '+DATE(' + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8).Text + ';1;3)-WEEKDAY(DATE(' + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8).Text + ';1;3))-2'
```

if I echo $test I got what I want :

```
=7*40+DATE(2014;1;3)-WEEKDAY(DATE(2014;1;3))-2
```

but when i put $test into my cell like this :

```
$newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1) = $test
```

Result an error :

```
Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC
Au caractère D:\Users\sadm\Documents\salesforce_1.ps1:839 : 1
+ $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1) = $tmp1
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

Comment: $test = `'=7*40+DATE(2014;1;3)-JOURSEM(DATE(2014;1;3))-2'`

Comment: Nop, i want to put the first variable
     $test = ("=7*" + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,9).Text + "+DATE(" + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8).Text + ";1;3)-JOURSEM(DATE(" + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8).Text + ";1;3))-2")

into 
    $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1)

Comment: `0x800A03EC` is `ERROR_INVALID_FLAGS`. Most likely there's something wrong with your interfacing with Excel. I would try to output `$test`. If it outputs something, the error is in setting the cell. If it doesn't, the error is in assigning to `$test`

Comment: Pasting that formula in Excel works for me. I assume it works for you to? Did you try `$newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1) = 0`? What is the value of $indexDate?

Comment: My excel at line 13 got 0 with :

`$newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1) = 0
     echo $indexDate
     echo $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1).Text`

Output : 
`13
0`

Comment: Pasting the formula in excel works? Perhaps [following](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1163664/52598) is relevant to you.

Comment: Yes it works for me too. 

Already did `[System.Threading.Thread]::CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = [System.Globalization.CultureInfo] "en-US"`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7099770/hresult-0x800a03ec-on-worksheet-range

Comment: https://duckduckgo.com/?q=HRESULT+%3A+0x800A03EC

Comment: i've test  lot of solution.. but doesn't work... Someone have an idea of my probleme ?

Comment: If you post a [minimal script](http://sscce.org/) that should do what you need and throws the error, I will give it a try here.

Comment: I try with an other powershell in 2.0 this one 
`$workbook1.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(5,5).formula='='+"7*40+DATE(2014;1;3)-JOURSEM(DATE(2014;1;3))-2"`

That's work. I did an update of powershell in 5.0 now that's doesn't work...

Comment: Can you post an [sscce](http://sscce.org)?

Comment: Problem Solved ... Just have to replace ";" by ","
`$workbook1.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(5,5).formula='='+"7*40+DATE(2014;1;3)-JOURSEM‌​(DATE(2014;1;3))-2"`

by

`$workbook1.ActiveSheet.Cells.Item(5,5).formula='='+"7*40+DATE(2014,1,3)-JOURSEM‌​(DATE(2014,1,3))-2"`

Thx Every body for your help

Answer (score 0):

I search to display a specific date with a number of week and a year.

Number of week and year are containing in cells of an excel.

```
$newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,9) = $idsem ##Here is my number of week
$newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8) = $tempDate3.ToString("yyyy")
$test = "=" + "7*" + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,9).Text + '+DATE(' + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8).Text + ';1;3)-JOURSEM(DATE(' + $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,8).Text + ';1;3))-2'
$newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1) = $test
$newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1).NumberFormat = "jj/mm/aaaa"
$global:indexDate++
```

When I launch the script with powershell 5.0 I had this error :

```
Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A03EC
Au caractère D:\Users\sadm\Documents\salesforce_1.ps1:831 : 1
+ $newWorkSheet.Cells.Item($indexDate,1) = $test
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
+ CategoryInfo          : OperationStopped: (:) [], COMException
+ FullyQualifiedErrorId : System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException
```

with 2.0 that works...