# Excel Interop Throws HRESULT: 0x800A03EC Error on Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing) C#

Tags: c#, .net, excel, office-interop, office-automation

I have a program that exports a Data Grid View to Excel file.
In one of my PCs runs correctly (Excel 2019), but when I use the same program on a PC that is having Excel 2016 and multiple users registered the Export function throws the Error HRESULT:  0x800A03EC

```
Excel.Application app=null;
                try
                {
                    app = new Excel.Application();
                    app.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing);

                    for (int i = 1; i < dgv_tickets.Columns.Count + 1; i++)
                    {
                    ...
                    }
                }
```

There Exception is thrown at line:
**app.Application.Workbooks.Add(Type.Missing)**

1. I tried to run the .exe as an Administrator
2. I used older COM assembly for the project

Any ideas on this particular error?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Excel error HRESULT: 0x800A03EC while trying to get range with cell's name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/891394/excel-error-hresult-0x800a03ec-while-trying-to-get-range-with-cells-name)

Comment: Don't use Excel Interop, there are a myriad of libraries to work directly with files and don't require a licensed installation of a particular Office version with a particular architecture. NPOI is my favorite, but again, dealer's choice!

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after trying every possible solution, I did a repair on Excel Application throught Windows. A pop up window appeared telling me that the Excel is installed as 32bit and the rest of Office is on 64bit so I press repair.
And this fixed the problem.