Throws exception HRESULT 0x800A03EC when calling a method
The application generates an Excel document from several files and produces the following error

System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException HRESULT 0x800A03EC

        public void Off(Excel.Application application)
        {
            application.EnableEvents = true;
            application.Calculation = Excel.XlCalculation.xlCalculationAutomatic; // Error HRESULT 0x800A03EC
            application.DisplayAlerts = true;
            application.DisplayStatusBar = true;
            application.ScreenUpdating = true;
        }


I tried searching on the Internet, but it didn't give any results.

Weird, the first google result for "excel hresult 0x800A03EC" is https://stackoverflow.com/q/891394/11683.

This is not exactly what I need

Errors that start with 0x800A are generated by Excel itself.  0x03EC = 1004, "Excel error 1004" is your google query.  There are rather a lot of possible causes, the fact that it gets generated when you enable calculation strongly suggests bad spreadsheet data.  Avoid turning off calculation and you'll likely catch the bad data when it is entered.  Loading the bad spreadsheet in Excel by hand might give you another good lead.

The official documentation says that this error occurs:

"When using an Excel action in which you need to specify a column,
row, or both, the column index must be greater than zero and less than
16,385, or the column letter must belong to the range between A and
XFD. In addition, the row index must be greater than zero and less
than 1,048,577."

