# Producing multiple worksheets in excel using C#

Tags: c#, excel

I need to produce a C# program which will create two intro worksheets, and a 3rd worksheet that will be made repeatedly for every entry in a database.  I am unsure which is the best way to produce multiple worksheets.  This last sheet must be able to retain some formating and range names. Is copying this last sheet better, or is creating a new worksheet better?

Comment: can you please elaborate your question, i can show you how to create new worksheets in excel using C#...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I do know how to create new worksheets.  What I am unsure about is, is it possible to create a template worksheet with named ranges and formating already done, then copy it x number of times filing in the ranges as I go?

Comment: Hmm, starting to wonder if this is a homework question or something... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1088539/using-templates-in-excel-with-c/1100985#1100985

Answer (score 1):

[SpreadsheetGear for .NET](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/) can do it.

See the "**Worksheet with Chart to Multiple Worksheets with Charts**" sample on the Excel Reporting samples page [here](http://www.spreadsheetgear.com/support/samples/excel.aspx) (there are other samples on that page which might prove useful).

You can download a free trial [here](https://www.spreadsheetgear.com/downloads/register.aspx).

Disclaimer: I own SpreadsheetGear LLC

Comment: You should "Disclaimer" to "Badge of Honor" - we use SpreadsheetGear and it's awesome.

Comment: That is very kind of you David - of course I'm just trying to follow the stackoverflow guidelines which suggest using "disclaimer" when writing about a product you have a personal interest in :)

Answer (score 0):

It depends on what you mean by better.  If it's easier to start with a clean slate for each sheet and just recopy the elements that are common, then creating new worksheets is better.

You could also create a temporary "template" sheet with the common elements already on it, and make copies of that.

Documentation for the Copy function is here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.copy(VS.80).aspx

Comment: Thank you for your reply, is if possible to copy a "template" worksheet and retain the formating and ranged names form the original or not?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your reply, is if possible to copy a "template" worksheet and retain the formating and ranged names form the original or not? – Slapdash 58 mins ago

Yes; that's possible. In the situation you describe I'd go for the copying option.

Answer (score 0):

Copying the third worksheet would be best.  Using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll, this is what the copy could look like (mExcelWorkbook is the template Workbook you want to edit):

```
  /// <summary>
  /// Copy a worksheet to the specified index
  /// </summary>
  /// <param name="worksheetIndex"></param>
  private void CopyWorksheetToIndex(int worksheetIndex, int copyToIndex)
  {
     if (mExcelWorkbook != null)
     {
        // Reference to the worksheet
        Worksheet sheet_to_copy = (Worksheet)mExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[worksheetIndex];
        // Set the Tab Name to something
        sheet_to_copy.Name = "Copied From " + worksheetIndex + " To " + copyToIndex;
        // Copy the worksheet to the end of the worksheets
        sheet_to_copy.Copy(System.Reflection.Missing.Value, mExcelWorkbook.Worksheets[copyToIndex]);
     }
  }
```

Then you could just call like this:

```
  if (mExcelWorkbook != null)
  {
     CopyWorksheetToIndex(3, mExcelWorkbook.Worksheets.Count);
  }
```