# Exporting 3 dataTables in C# to an Excel Workbook

Tags: c#, excel, datatable

I have 3 sepereate datatables in C# I want to export to a single Excel Workbook, each on different sheets.  Is there an easy way to do this?  I thought about adding the tables to a single dataset, but that didn't seem possible.  I wrote a method that can convert a single dataTable into a csv file, but that doesn't work for multiple tables.  Thanks!

I used the first link and it's creating an Excel, but then it crashes for two reasons:
The way it resized the columns didn't work:

```
// Resize the columns 
oRange = oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1],
    oSheet.Cells[rowCount, dt.Columns.Count]);
```

And I added this to make a second sheet and it didn't work:

```
Excel.Worksheet sheet2;
oWB.Sheets.Add(name[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing); 
sheet2 = (Excel.Worksheet)oWB.Sheets[1];
```

I can figure out how to fix my code and add another sheet, but does anyone know why the resize columns isn't working?

Comment: "Didn't work" is pretty vague - what happened instead of it working?  did you get an error message? If so, what was it?  You have a typo here `Excel.Worksheet sheet 2` (extra space).  `Sheets.Add()` returns the new sheet, so you can just use `sheet2 = oWB.Sheets.Add(...)`

Answer (score 0):

http://msmvps.com/blogs/deborahk/archive/2009/07/23/writing-data-from-a-datatable-to-excel.aspx

Just add another sheet and export the second and third tables to the new sheets

Another link with details:

[C# how to add Excel Worksheet programmatically Office XP / 2003](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/193092/c-sharp-how-to-add-excel-worksheet-programatically-office-xp-2003)

Make sure you catch the return.

```
xlNewSheet = (Worksheet)xlSheets.Add(xlSheets[1], Type.Missing, Type.Missing, Type.Missing);
```

Comment: Thanks!  I tried adding sheets but I caused a problem.  Also, it's throwing an exception at the line:   oRange = oSheet.get_Range(oSheet.Cells[1, 1], oSheet.Cells[rowCount, dt.Columns.Count]);  saying there isn't a get_Range.  It's a great start so thanks again!  :)

Comment: @Miriam - update your question with the problem code: very difficult to debug a single line!